# Add custom bg color and logo option for a div in header from admin panel theme options - wp twenty eleven theme

Tags: header, wordpress, themes, wordpress-theming

I'm new to wordpress.. I have created a custom theme with files of twenty eleven theme in wordpress. But I'm not able to add custom background option and custom logo option. I'm trying to implement it in theme options page. I want to add a custom background color to a div in header section and also a logo in header.

Please give any suggestions for me to complete this theme creation.

Please give some idea about how to add new fields in theme options page and how to display it in pages..

I also want to add some custom text field for displaying address or some lines of text which can be updated from theme options.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try wp codex (https://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Customization_API), it'll help you with setting up the default wp customizer.
I personally use both the default customiser and the OptionTree plugin (http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/option-tree/), the plugin is really easy to implement, I'd suggest you start with that.